# Synchronization aid in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am running a web server. Each user request will update/lookup the database. the max no of simultaneous db connections should be < N. The N+1 th concurrent request should back out and perform other logic instead of connecting to db. What i can think of to do this is to use Atomic integer which will be incremented/decremented by each request while connecting to db.

My Question is, is there any other synchronization aid available in java for this other than Atomic Integer? I dont think i can use CountDownLatch or Cyclic barrier for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Semaphore`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) is the most suitable synchronization primitive for this case:

```
private Semaphore s = new Semaphore(N);

public void doRequest() {
    if (s.tryAquire()) {
        try {
            ...
        } finally {
            s.release();
        }
    } else {
        // other logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try an [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) of connections. Initialize the queue with N.

1. Initialize the queue with N
2. Fill the N connections.
3. Whenever someone needs a connection, first do q.poll()
4. If q.poll() returns null, then doe your "perform other logic"
5. After usage put back the connection to pool.

But I will urge to use existing solutions like [proxool](http://proxool.sourceforge.net/) for this.

Comment: @shk as suraj suggested, you can also go with LinkedBlockingQueue, which has high throughput.

Answer (score 1):

Alternately you could use a connection pool such as [Apache Commons DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp) that will handle the connections for you and can either wait for a connection when there isn't one or will throw and exception which you can handle.

Comment: Yeah, two databases are used. for one db, dbcp will be used and for the other db(remote machine), will create and close the connection for each request.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the suraj's answer , I think your problem is more of `producer consumer` , i prefer `LinkedBlockingQueue` for more throughput.